# Movespeed calculation issue

Tags: c++

This is in C++ and I'm using VC++ 2010.

I am creating a tile-based game, each tile is 32 pixels. If you are given an amount of time, and in that time you want to move an image 32 pixels in a direction, how would I calculate the amount to move per each frame? The frame rate is not fixed and I have access to the frame delta time.

If you need more information just ask.

Comment: If you're asking if I am using integer division with this, then yes. The coordinates are all in integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic formula you need to calculate it is:

*P pixels / S seconds * delta T seconds/frame = X pixels/frame*

For example we'll use your tile size and move it in 1 second and the current frame rate is 30 fps.

*32 pixels / 1 second * .033 seconds/frame = 1.056 pixels/frame*

```
int P = 32;
double S = 1.0;
double T = getFrameTime();
double X = P / S * T;
```

Comment: Your math is off a bit. You should be dividing by `S` seconds, not multiplying or the units will come out wrong.

Comment: You're absolutely right Mike. Thanks for pointing that out. It should be fixed now.